# .Net - How to create UserControl that implements an interface? Error with LoadControl

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, user-controls

I have a number of UserControls that I want to each have some basic functionality. Below is my implementation :

```
public interface IMyTabInterface
{
    void LoadData();
}

public partial class MyFirstTab : System.Web.UI.UserControl, IMyTabInterface
{
    public void LoadData()
    {
        ...
    }

}
```

Then, in another page's code behind, I try :

```
    protected void LoadFirstTab()
    {
        Control uControl1 = Page.LoadControl("/Controls/MyFirstTab.ascx");
        Control uControl2 = Page.LoadControl("/Controls/MySecondTab.ascx");

        // Want to do something like this, but don't get this far... :
        var myFirstTab = (IMyTabInterface)uControl1;
        var mySecondTab = (IMyTabInterface)uControl2;

        myFirstTab.LoadData();
        mySecondTab.LoadData();

        Panel1.Controls.Add(myFirstTab);
        Panel1.Controls.Add(mySecondTab);
    }
```

I know much of this is not correct yet, but I am getting an error on the LoadControl() line :

**'MyFirstTab' is not allowed here because it does not extend class 'System.Web.UI.UserControl'**

even though the class clearly extends the UserControl class. Whats going on here? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will work:

```
var myFirstTab = (IMyTabInterface)uControl1;
var mySecondTab = (IMyTabInterface)uControl2;

myFirstTab.LoadData();
mySecondTab.LoadData();

Panel1.Controls.Add((Control)myFirstTab);
Panel1.Controls.Add((Control)mySecondTab);
```

What is going on?

Your `myFirstTab` and `mySecondTab` variables are of type `IMyTabInterface`, since this is what you declared them as (this is what allows you to call `LoadData` on them).

However, in order to *add* an item to the controls collection, these need to be of type `Control` (or one that inherits from it) - this is achieved by the cast.

---

Another option:

```
var myFirstTab = (IMyTabInterface)uControl1;
var mySecondTab = (IMyTabInterface)uControl2;

myFirstTab.LoadData();
mySecondTab.LoadData();

Panel1.Controls.Add(uControl1);
Panel1.Controls.Add(uControl2);
```

Here you use the original `Control` types you started with, so no need to cast.

Comment: Hi Oded, Thank you for your reply. I totally made a bonehead mistake and this question should be deleted - I had changed the namespace on the control thats why the LoadControl() function was breaking. Doh! Only realized this after I scrapped all my interface code to start over only to still get the same errors. Woops.